# i have been using tor but now i am unable to connect to tor network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

this is the

```
12/8/2016 18:50:47 PM.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
12/8/2016 18:50:57 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/8/2016 18:50:57 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/8/2016 18:50:57 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/8/2016 18:50:58 PM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Please post the full log, but your connection seems to be filtered. Try to seed this instance via other working connection - it may help. But generally you need to elaborate pluggable transports

Comment: i think your isp is blocking connections through tor try using the procedure below
[![step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gwmk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gwmk.png)
[![step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKFe1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKFe1.png)